# Trying to calculate the width of a text in my Nuxt App

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

This website functions like other typing test websites, where the user receives a text and needs to type the words. Currently, the text is always divided into sets of three lines. When the user finishes typing the second line, it moves up, and the user continues typing on the third line.

To calculate the line division, I test how many words I can fit in a sentence without the line exceeding the container's width, where the lines will be displayed. To achieve this, I use the function "getTextWidth," which creates a span with the same style as the website and retrieves the width of this span.

Initially, everything was working perfectly. However, after I started using an external font, things started to go wrong. Some lines are occupying two lines instead of one in some situations.

I tried several things, like changing fonts, adjusting sizes, checking the span tags to see if they had the style, rendering them, among many others. I believe that somehow, when the span is created, it's not receiving the styling, causing the lines to be smaller, and my code thinks they fit, but I could be wrong.

All the code is above, yeah its big, but i can be missing something, so i put the whole component

```
<template>
    <div class="typing-container">
        <div id="text-container">
            <div v-for="(line, lineId) in displayedLines" :key="lineId">
                <span v-for="(letter, letterId) in line.line" :key="letterId">
                    <span v-if="data.letterIndex === data.absoluteLetterIndexex[lineId+data.lineIndex][letterId]"  class="text-line"></span>
                    <span :style="{color: data.colors[data.absoluteLetterIndexex[lineId+data.lineIndex][letterId]]}">{{letter}}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'rotate']" />
    </div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

    import { computed, reactive, onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { useTypingStore } from '../../store/typing/typingStore'
    import { Word, Line } from './types';

    const store = useTypingStore();
    const { $axios } = useNuxtApp();

    const data = reactive({
        text: "",
        letterIndex: 0,
        wordIndex:0,
        lineIndex: 0,
        colors: [] as string[],
        words: [] as Word[],
        lines: [] as Line[],
        absoluteLetterIndexex: [] as number[][] 
    })

    function keyPressed(event: KeyboardEvent){
        const { key } = event;

        const regex = /^[a-zA-Z'.,:?!;()-]$/;

        const currentWord = data.words[data.wordIndex];
        const lastWord = data.words[data.wordIndex-1] ?? null;
        // just for reducing boiler plate from the data word

        if(regex.test(key)){ // if its a normal text letter
            if(key === data.text[data.letterIndex]){  // if its the right letter
                data.colors[data.letterIndex] = 'white'
                data.words[data.wordIndex].lettersLeft--;
                if(data.letterIndex === data.absoluteLetterIndexex[data.lineIndex+1][data.absoluteLetterIndexex[data.lineIndex+1].length-2]){ // if the letter is the last from the second line (-2 because there is always a empty space in the end)
                    data.lineIndex++;
                }
            }else{
                data.colors[data.letterIndex] = 'red';
            }
            data.words[data.wordIndex].lastWritedIndex = data.letterIndex +1;
            data.letterIndex+=1;
        }else{
            if(key === "Backspace"){

                if(data.letterIndex <= 0 ){ //start of the text cannot go back
                    return;   
                }

                if(data.wordIndex-1 >=0 && data.letterIndex === currentWord.start && lastWord.lettersLeft === 0){ // If we are at the beginning of the word and are trying to do a backspace, which would make us go back to the last word, so we gotta check if it wasn't already complete.
                    return;
                }
                
                if (currentWord.start > data.letterIndex - 1){ // if we are in the start of a word and do a backspace we need to go to the last writed letter in the previous word
                    data.letterIndex = lastWord.lastWritedIndex;
                    data.words[data.wordIndex].lastWritedIndex =  data.words[data.wordIndex].start;
                    data.wordIndex--;
                }else{
                    data.letterIndex-=1;
                    if(data.colors[data.letterIndex] === "white"){ // if i'm deleting a already correct letter there will be one more letter left
                        data.words[data.wordIndex].lettersLeft++;
                        data.words[data.wordIndex].lastWritedIndex--;
                    }
                    data.colors[data.letterIndex] = "gray";
                }
            }
            if(key === ' ' && currentWord.start !== data.letterIndex){
                data.letterIndex = data.words[++data.wordIndex].start
                
            }
        }
    }

    function setData( text: string ){
        let newWords: Word[] = [];
        let length = 0;
        let word = "";
        let start=0,lastWritedIndex;

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if(text[i] !== ' '){
            length++;
            word+=text[i];
          }else{
            newWords.push({
              start,
              word,
              length,
              lastWritedIndex: start,
              index: newWords.length,
              lettersLeft: length
            });
            start = i+1;
            word = "";
            length= 0
          }
        }
        data.words = newWords;
        data.text = text
        data.lines = divideTextInLines();
        data.colors = (new Array(data.text.length).fill('gray'))
    }

    async function getRandomText(){
        const text = ((await $axios.get('http://metaphorpsum.com/paragraphs/6')).data.replace(/\n/g, ' '));
        setData(text)
    }

    function divideTextInLines() {
        
        let lines: Line[] = [];
        let currentLine = "";
        let cumulativeCharacters= 0;
        const containerWidth = document.getElementById("text-container")?.offsetWidth;


        for (let i = 0; i < data.words.length; i++) {
            const word = data.words[i].word;
            const lineWithWord = currentLine ? currentLine + " " + word : word;
            const lineWidth = getTextWidth(lineWithWord);

            if (containerWidth && lineWidth <= containerWidth) {
                currentLine = lineWithWord;
            } else {
                console.log(currentLine, lineWidth);
                currentLine+= " ";
                lines.push({
                    line: currentLine,
                    cumulativeCharacters
                });
                
                let lineAbsoluteIndexes = [];
                for (let j = 0; j < currentLine.length; j++) {
                    lineAbsoluteIndexes.push(cumulativeCharacters + j);
                }
                data.absoluteLetterIndexex.push(lineAbsoluteIndexes);
                cumulativeCharacters += currentLine.length;
                currentLine = word;
            }
        }

        if (currentLine) {
            currentLine+= " ";
            lines.push({
                line: currentLine,
                cumulativeCharacters
            });
            let lineAbsoluteIndexes = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < currentLine.length; j++) {
                lineAbsoluteIndexes.push(cumulativeCharacters + j);
            }
            data.absoluteLetterIndexex.push(lineAbsoluteIndexes);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    function getTextWidth(text: string) {
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        const spanStyles = {
            fontSize: '1.7rem',
            fontFamily: 'RobotMono',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            visibility: 'hidden',
        };

        Object.assign(span.style, spanStyles);

        span.innerText = text;
        console.log(span)
        document.body.appendChild(span);
        const width = span.offsetWidth;
        document.body.removeChild(span);
        return width;
    }

    const colors = computed(()=>{
        return data.colors;
    })

    const displayedLines = computed(()=>{
        return data.lines.slice(data.lineIndex, data.lineIndex+3);
    })

    onMounted(()=>{
        window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed )
        getRandomText();
    })

</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
    #text-container{
        width: 80rem;
        max-width: 90%;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        font-family: RobotMono;
    }
    .text-line{
        padding: 2px 1px;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .typing-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 3rem;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be that the measured width of the spans you're creating isn't accurate until an asynchronous layout task is performed.

I've written my own utility function for measuring text width by creating a canvas to avoid this issue. It can be found in [@tubular/util](https://github.com/kshetline/tubular_util). This is the code for the function:

```
export function getTextWidth(items: string | string[], font: string | HTMLElement, fallbackFont?: string): number {
  const canvas = ((getTextWidth as any).canvas as HTMLCanvasElement ||
                  ((getTextWidth as any).canvas = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement));
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
  let maxWidth = 0;
  let elementFont;

  if (typeof font === 'string')
    elementFont = font;
  else if (typeof font === 'object')
    elementFont = getFont(font);

  if (elementFont)
    context.font = elementFont;
  else if (fallbackFont)
    context.font = fallbackFont;
  else
    context.font = 'normal 12px sans-serif';

  if (!Array.isArray(items))
    items = [items];

  for (const item of items) {
    const width = context.measureText(item).width;
    maxWidth = max(maxWidth, width);
  }

  return maxWidth;
}
```

Comment: I used but had the same problem, nothing change. But tankhs for sharing your lib

Comment: Solve today, the problem was that the fonts were not being loaded in time for the span. 

just add "await document.fonts.ready;" and made everything async